# Android: How to set timeout for OutputStream?

Tags: android, sockets, outputstream, ioexception

I used `Socket` to communicate with Client. I've problem for setting the timeout for `OutputStream`. The Socket itself already set the timeout. When I didn't set the timeout for OutputStream, when the internet connection is shut down at `OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream()`, the `IOException` will thrown **after 15 minutes**. It will affect the user experience itself.

**Socket.java**

```
 // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
 final SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

 SSLSocket socket = null;

 try{
     SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = context.getSocketFactory();
     socket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket();
     socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(<dstAddress>, <dstPort>), <timeout>);

     // Here is the point when the internet connection is loss
     OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
     out.write(BytesUtil.hexStringToBytes(<requestParams>));
     out.flush();
  } catch(SocketTimeoutException se) {
     se.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     // Will thrown after 15 minutes
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     // close socket
     if (socket != null) {
        try {
           socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **Socket** and **ServerSocket**. Both classes have a **setSoTimeout** method to specify the maximum time to wait when waiting for connections or waiting to receive data. When that time has elapsed, the socket throws a SocketTimeoutException that you can handle with your error message or however you want.
You have to call `setSoTimeout()` before performing the actions you want to have a timeout.
Prior to

```
while ((numberReceived = socketInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
//You'll need to call
socket.setSoTimeout(2000);
```

And then add a catch(SocketTimeoutException) section to the try/catch block you already have.